# Populating a database with mock data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am writing a Rake task to populate the database with some mock data that they have given to me, so for example if there is a Organization table that has a name, id and time_zone field I wanted to populate it in my rake task, so first I created an array of my sample Organizations:

```
SAMPLE_ORGANIZATIONS = [ '37 Signals', 'Fog Creek']
```

And then a method to populate database from that:

```
def create_organizations
  SAMPLE_ORGANIZATIONS.each_with_index  {|item, index|
    Organization.first_or_create(
        name: item,
        time_zone: 'Central'
    )
  }
end
```

Is it a good way?  How can I improve it?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options.

1. Put your mock code in db/seeds.rb, then run `rake db:seed`
2. Fixtures. Define the data in yaml files, then run `rake db:fixtures:load`.
3. Factory Girl. Probably the best choice, but slightly more complicated. Put your FactoryGirl code in db/seeds.rb and use it like #1.